# Lambda function explained in Java

Tags: java

I am quite new to Java, and I read some open-source code then I found this block of code. After some findings, I don't know that did I understand it correctly or not.

```
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new CBORFactory())

public byte[] toByteArray() {
        PersistentTemplate persistent = new PersistentTemplate(immutable.mutable());
        return Exceptions.wrap().get(() -> mapper.writeValueAsBytes(persistent));
}
```

What I think is this block of code tries to catch the exception of the lambda function that doesn't have a parameter. In this code, lambda function is `mapper` object call `writeValueAsBytes` method.

What the lambda function is doing is serializing a Java Object into JSON using the `writeValueAsBytes` method of `ObjectMapper` class. Am I understand it correctly?

**Update:**

`Exceptions` class

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public final class Exceptions {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Exceptions.class);
    private static final ExceptionPassThrough pass = new ExceptionPassThrough();
    private static final ExceptionLogger log;
    private static final ExceptionSilencer silence;
    private static final ExceptionSmuggler sneak;
    private static final ExceptionWrapper wrap;

    private Exceptions() {
    }

    public static ExceptionHandler pass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public static ExceptionHandler log() {
        return log;
    }

    public static ExceptionHandler log(Logger logger) {
        return new ExceptionLogger(logger, "Caught exception");
    }

    public static ExceptionHandler log(Logger logger, String message) {
        return new ExceptionLogger(logger, message);
    }

    public static ExceptionHandler silence() {
        return silence;
    }

    public static CheckedExceptionHandler sneak() {
        return sneak;
    }

    public static CheckedExceptionHandler wrap() {
        return wrap;
    }

    public static CheckedExceptionHandler wrap(Function<Exception, RuntimeException> wrapper) {
        return new ExceptionTransform(wrapper);
    }

    static {
        log = new ExceptionLogger(logger, "Caught exception");
        silence = new ExceptionSilencer();
        sneak = new ExceptionSmuggler();
        wrap = new ExceptionWrapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Exceptions`? Can you give the fully-qualified name for that class?

Comment: @Sweeper I just update the `Exception` class code.